# Mount external disk via curlftps as a service

Tags: mount, systemd, curlftpfs

If I have an external drive I access via FTPS, how can I add a systemctl service to mount it and unmount it and have it mount it upon start-up? I already saw some examples with scripts and crontab but I found them too incoherent and hard to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the directory where you'd like to mount the drive

```
mkdir /mnt/ftp-drive
```

Create now the file `/etc/systemd/system/external-ftp.service` with this content (your `systemd/system` dir might be in a different location):

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount FTP Space
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/curlftpfs -o ssl,no_verify_peer,nonempty,user=<user>:<pass> <host> /mnt/ftp-drive/ -f -v
ExecStop=/bin/fusermount -u /mnt/ftp-drive

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note the `-f` option to make `curlftps` run as daemon. `ExecStart` and `ExecStop` need full path of commands, that is, note the full path of `curlftps` and `fusermount`. In your case may be different, find the full path with `sudo find / -name curlftps -type f`.

Now you just start the service

```
sudo service external-ftp start
```

if everything is OK, you should be able to access `/mnt/ftp-drive` and the command `sudo service external-ftp status` should return OK.

If everything is OK, activate the service to start on boot:

```
sudo systemctl enable external-ftp
```